# Why can a field not be used to make a quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In socratica's [youtube](https://youtu.be/IvukAijXgLE?list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6&t=408) video (which should be required for every abstract algebra class), she is explaining that a motivation for modules as rings allow you to do things that you can't do with fields. If you have a ring with an ideal $I\triangleleft R$ where M is an R module you can create an R/I quotient ring. Why can't you do this with a field?

[image]

Comment: If $F$ is a field, the only ideals are $\{0\}$ and $F$. You *can* do it, but you don’t get anything interesting: just $F$ again, or the trivial module.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ahhh! add that as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, its only ideals are $\{0\}$ and $F$. You can do it, but you either get the trivial ring/module or $F$ again. So it is not interesting to do it for fields. It’s not that you can’t do it, but rather that there is no point in doing it.